# Training set before intensive snowboarding week

Tags: training, sports

I'm going for a one week long trip to learn snowboarding in the Alps. I was told by a friend that after the first day, your body is exhausted, and doesn't recover for several days. I imagine this is because snowboarding intensively uses muscles that are not normally used so.

So, in order to make the most of the trip, I would like to train some of those muscles in advance. But I have no idea which muscles these are (so cannot figure out a proper workout).

I would like some one with experience on snowboarding to give me some information on what muscles are key to snowboard (particularly for beginners). A set of exercises particularly tailored for snowboarding would be most welcomed too, but not necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not just the muscles that aren't used to being used. It's highly about how high up you are and the cold. Your body doesn't get the oxygen it is used to and your muscles become extra tired through this.

Answer (score -1):

I was snowboarding until a few years ago when I changed to alpine skiing. I remember that it was really hard on the core, especially if you are tall like me (191 cm). So I would do core exercises: plank -> swissball plank and sideplank almost every day.
Also if you can find a large boso ball; you can stand on the flat side of this mimicking snowboarding.